# New entity persisted with NULL id (id=0)

Tags: oracle10g, hibernate-4.x

I'm using **Hibernate 4.3.11**.
I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ESP_RETARD")
public class ESP_RETARD implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "pk_seqret", sequenceName = "ESP_RETS_SEQ1", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk_seqret")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private long idRetard;
```

I tried to persist a new entity on **ESP_RETARD**.

But, I encounter a problem: a new entity is added, **however, it's with id 0**.

the second time to add a new one, I got this exception:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could
>   not execute statement
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: unique constraint
>   (EDTINGA.SYS_C009525) violated

Knowing that: when I used:

- Hibernate 3 with 
  [those jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrDKC.png), 
  I didn't get this issue.
- But once I upgraded to Hibernate 4.3.11 with [those jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdKYe.png), I encountred this excpetion.

==> So it's a problem of jars, I suppose that it's missed jar(s) have to be added to **Hibernate 4.3.11**.

Have you please any idea about solving that issue ?.
Big thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try removing the entire entity and then re-create it with **new table name** and **new column name** for the id.

Don't forgot to change the nomination on `@SequenceGenerator` and `@GeneratedValue`.

Indeed, it's not necessary to use neither `@Column(nullable = false)` nor `@NotNull`.

```
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "pk_seqret1", sequenceName = "RETS_SEQ1", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk_seqret1")
    private long idRetard;
```

HTH.